# Send Keys {ENTER} To specific Windows Pop-up

Tags: c#

All, I am new to C# so apologies if this is a simple question.

I have an automation which navigates through a variety of links to carry out a process, however sporadically (Unsure of the root cause as of yet) the below windows error pop up which requires manual intervention user needs to select {ENTER}

[image]

I am using the below code to send {ENTER} every 2 minutes incase the above pop-up occurs. *(Time Interval and condition to send {ENTER} is outside of the c# script below:*

```
    public void SendKeys_ENTER()
    {
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
```

I would like to know if it is possible to identify through c# that the above pop-up is active on the screen and only then send the keys {ENTER} and once the {ENTER} key is pressed validate the pop-up has been destroyed.

**New Code I am trying to implement with suggestions made on this post**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Xml;

 namespace Dynamic.Script_8D737880D773F26
    { **Error parenthesis
    // Script generated by Pega Robotics Studio 8.0.2032.0
    // Please use caution when modifying class name, namespace or attributes
    [OpenSpan.TypeManagement.DynamicTypeAttribute()]
    [OpenSpan.Design.ComponentIdentityAttribute("Script-8D737880D773F26")]
    public sealed class Script
    {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
   static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    }

    public bool ScriptErrorVisible()
    {
        if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
            return true;
            }

        else
            {
            return false;
            }

        }
    }
} **Error parenthesis
```

I am now getting an error where I have labelled **Error parenthesis if anyone can suggest what is wrong with the code that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the browser to be visible? Do you need to use Internet Explorer?!

Comment: If you want out of the box automation check out AHK

Comment: Use the `FindWindow` WinAPI function to check whether a window with title "Script Error" is visible.

Comment: If using IE from .Net set `SuppressScriptErrors= true`

Comment: @dymanoid are you able to provide a quick example of how I can check the window with a title "Script Error" is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the WinAPI function `FindWindow` to check whether a window with particular title is currently visible.

Since `FindWindow` is a native function, you will need to call it using P/Invoke (Plattform Invoke). There is a nice [web resource pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) that provides you a lot of helpful info.

So, declare the external function in your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
```

And then just call it somewhere:

```
if (FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Script Error") != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // window is visible
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried to implement the answer you have provided but my basic c# knowledge is failing me. Could you just recommend what is missing in my edited script! Again really appreciate your help with this.